# Corpus for Asian American Accents?

Tags: accent

I'm looking for a corpus of Asian American accents so that I might parse them and determine what phonetic/ phonological differences differentiate them from other American accents.

By Asian-American accents, I'm thinking something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1I3hWOxsy8), wherein the speaker is a US-born native English speaker with little to no proficiency in Chinese or another East/ Southeast Asian language, but whose parents speak the given East/ Southeast Asian language heavily in the home and whose L2 English itself is accented.

The male speaker at 0:22 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJDn-rLv53E) would be a good example for a male Asian American accent.

It's an oddly specific request, but I can provide more examples if there's difficulty determining what accent I'm talking about.

Comment: A place to start is the [George Mason Speech Accent Archive](http://accent.gmu.edu/). It isn't a corpus, but it matches up phonetics, sound files, and native and non-native accents by location and native language. It'll at least give you some idea what to look for.